# Removing metal cap of a Crystal Oscillator

Tags: integrated-circuit

We want to remove the metal cap on top to examine the inside. Datasheet says it's a sealed IC for protection from environment. How can we remove of metal cap to see it under the microscope? It is in size about 2mm

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: Looks like a crystal to me. [Not very exciting](http://www.comtec-crystals.com/products/product_images/normal/cxo7050_open.jpg).

Comment: What happened to your tweezers?!?

Comment: yes crystal, but each one is different in details.

Comment: I suggest that you change the title as this is not an IC but a crystal or a crystal oscillator (which will include a die with an IC inside). Nearly all modern ICs are glued on a metal frame (lead frame) and plastic is molded on top of that to form the IC package.

Comment: OK, you're right. Actually I'm going to move from crystal to an IC like a filter in the next step.

Comment: What is between plastic and metal hats? How do they hold each other?

Comment: That's ceramic, not plastic. There's metallization on the ceramic, and the metal lid is soldered to the metal on the ceramic case, usually with a higher temperature solder so the lid doesn't come off during normal handling.

Comment: Can i remove metal cap applying high temperature with a heat gun?

Comment: Why do you want to examine the inside if I may ask?

Comment: Roughly this https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/8/84/Quarzhalter.JPG but much much smaller, along with a sand grain sized IC.

Answer (score 6):

If you want to be sure, order a replacement identical part and take the lid off it using a milling machine. Then you can modify your approach to the real device based on the successes or failures in milling the replacement. If necessary, step and repeat on more replacements until you are sure your technique is correct.

Comment: We have one, so maybe people with experience can lead by production technique for removing cap.

Comment: If you feel brave ;-) and don't mind that the component is destroyed then you could also try a Dremel instead of the milling machine.

Comment: I'm talking about removing the hat, how can I see it all details when I make a hole from above? Please provide details.

Comment: @BerkerIşık if you have enough, why don't you just start milling/grinding off the top? It's not like we'll start posting videos of us doing that for you.

Comment: @BerkerIşık I don't think there is any single "production technique" for delidding a package. In a production environment we would know how the package was assembled, which would suggest a reliable way to reverse the assembly process. Without that information you will always be taking a risk of damaging the device.

Comment: Having one of something and messing with it doesn't seem like a real good approach, if the outcome is important.

Comment: Yes i agree, people say I need to get a drill in my hand right away, not knowing how something is manufactured and despite my desire to understand.

Comment: @BerkerIşık if we are done with this Q and A session then please accept an answer.